# How do I start a new game in Assassin's Creed: Unity?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I have completed playing the main sequence of the game. Now I would like to play from the start again. I don't seem to find a new game option in the menu. Am I missing something?

I would like to play the game again after the patch 3 is released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Delete the save files located in your Ubisoft Savegame folder under
>     Program Files(x86).
> - Then when you are prompted to pick a save file by
>     the Uplay launcher pick to use the local one.
>
> You should be able to
>   start anew and when it syncs with the cloud again it will overwrite
>   your old save with your new one.

**Be sure to take a backup in case you change your mind.**

Comment: This doesn't give an answer for console players.

Comment: Be sure to turn off Cloud Sync in Uplay launcher settings before starting game back up

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work (anymore?). When deleting the save games (or the entire savegames directory), it just downloads the save files from the cloud save without asking to choose. Who the hell designs a game without a new game button, it's as if they didn't want people to ever play again ... I skipped the beginning cutscenes because I wanted to just quit the game again after installing it, now I can't get them to start again -.-

Answer (score 3):

For PS4, Make sure the game is not running. Go to Settings>System Storage Management>Application Saved Data>Assasins Creed Unity>Delete All 3 Item> Start New Game.

This will remove all saved data on the game so if you want to keep your old progress you should not do this!

Answer (score 3):

For xbox one go to games and apps, find the game and press the back button on the controller, next scroll over your xbox live name and press A and then pick whether you want to delete your data from the console you are playing on or on every console the account is connected to.